# Angular - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message') at AuthComponent.tokenHandler

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET Core Web API as backend and Angular-13 as frontend.

When successful, the endpoint on POSTMAN gives:

```
{
   "status_code": 200,
   "message": "Successfully Logged In",
   "result": {
       "token": "gggggffffffffffffdddddddddddd",
       "user": {
           "id": 3,
           "user_name": "smith",
           "last_login": "2022-01-03T12:35:26.0305649"
          },
       "roles": [
           "Teacher"
       ],
       "expires": "2022-01-03T14:40:33Z"
   }
}
```

Then for error, I have:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'user')"
}
```

When Login is successful in Angular frontend, I want to display the message:

> message": "Successfully Logged In"

as it's on POSTMAN

auth.component:

```
login(){
  this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe({
    next: (res) => this.toastr.success(res.message),
    error: (error) => {
      this.toastr.error(error.message);
    }
  })
}
```

I got this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
> at AuthComponent.tokenHandler (auth.component.ts:59)

This is the line it points at:

> this.toastr.success(data.message);

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need in `auth.component.ts` explicitly `next:` and `error:`?

Comment: @Chaka15 - How do you mean?

Comment: Why you used `{}` inside `subscribe` with both `next:` and `error:`? Can you just remove it and write two regular arrow functions?

Comment: Do this 

    tokenHandler(message: any){
      this.toastr.success(message);
    }
since you already passed the message.

Comment: @Chaka15 - I added next: and error because Angular crossed .subscribe and says it's deprecated. However when I removed {} and write two regular arrow functions as you advised, the error still came up:    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message') at AuthComponent.tokenHandler (auth.component.ts:59):

Comment: Just to point out, it's weird that `.subscribe` is marked as deprecated...

Comment: @Chaka15 It's not weird at all. Since rxjs6.4, all subscribe signatures that accept more than 1 argument are deprecated. You can read it [here](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments)

Comment: Oh, yes. Curly braces should be removed both with `next:` and `error:`, though it doesn't solve the issue itself.

Comment: @midowu have you checked the response in the browser devtools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
tokenHandler(message: any){
  this.toastr.success(message);
}
```

since you already passed the message in the **function**.

Answer (score 0):

if in nodejs project not assign this then generate this

var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());

Answer (score 0):

I changed the login method to

```
login() {
this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(res => {
  this.toastr.success(res.message)
}, (error) => {
  this.toastr.error(error.message);
});}
```